# How to perform calculations for Fibonacci series in python or ruby?(without recursion)

Tags: python, ruby, fibonacci

I tried to find the nth term of the Fibonacci series in both Python and Ruby languages, but I could not get the expected output. Can anyone please help me?
My question is that they would give me first and second term with the nth term to find and I've to find my nth term.

My program in Python:

```
num1=int(raw_input())
num2=int(raw_input())
num=int(raw_input())
for i in range(3,num+1):
    sum=num1+num2
    num1=num2
    num2=sum
print sum
```

My program in Ruby:

```
num1=gets.to_i
num2=gets.to_i
num=gets.to_i
for i in 3..num:
    sum=num1+num2
    num1=num2
    num2=sum
print sum
```

Sample Input

```
0 1 5
```

Sample Output

```
5
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I couldn't get the correct output(nth term in fibonacci series)

Comment: Generally speaking, you should put your current output when asking for debug help. The ruby version is not a valid ruby code. Also, why do you get from input `num1` or `num2` as they should always be `0,1` or `1,1` (depending on your definition). You also didn't declare `sum=0` at the start.

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining my question correctly. I'll edit it now. Can you please help me because now only I am starting to learn this.

Comment: @RagaVarshini have a look up this thread - especially the answer: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87523/70853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python.

You have two consecutive numbers num1 and num2 of the fibonacci sequence. Let's call the position of num2 i. You want to find the term of the sequence at the position i+n(where n in your case is num). Following your code, this works:

```
num1 = int(raw_input())
num2 = int(raw_input())
num = int(raw_input())
for i in range(1, num+1):
    sum = num1 + num2
    num1 = num2
    num2 = sum
print sum
```

Input

```
0 1 5
```

Output

```
8
```

If you want to simply find the nth term of the sequence you can use this function:

```
def f(n):
    num1, num2 = 0, 1
    for _ in range(1, n+1):
        num1, num2 = num2, num1+num2
    return num2
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby

```
alpha = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2
beta  = (1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2
((alpha ** n - beta ** n) / Math.sqrt(5)).round
```

Comment: While this doesn't help him debug his code, +1 for showing the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby version is close:

```
num1=gets.to_i
num2=gets.to_i
num=gets.to_i
for i in 3..num     # no :
    sum=num1+num2
    num1=num2
    num2=sum
end                 # explicit end
print sum
```